# How can I send an SMS from iPhone simulator 4.0?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have gone through [this tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/) for sending SMS from an iPhone.

This is giving me an alertView with the message:

> textMessage is not enabled on this device.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iPhone Simulator does not simulate in-app SMS. You can only test this functionality on an iPhone device.

Comment: Yes you'll need to install your app on a device and test/debug from there. The code says nothing about the simulator, or any testing for the matter; it just shows you how to implement in-app SMS using code.

Comment: tell me one more thing i will send sms in India(Mobile)....so i have to do something for that also....??

Comment: You need a messaging contract. Just like when you own a normal mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t send messages from the Simulator.